# using a specific row to create a new list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of this form

[image]

i want to make a list using row 223. how do I make a list using all the columns of 223

my output should be

list:
0
57
166
178
and so on

Comment: use: `df.loc[223].to_list()`

Answer (score 2):

If need numeric values before `:` select row `223` and then select first digits:

```
L = df.loc[223].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).tolist()
```

Or split by `:` and select first sublists:

```
L = df.loc[223].str.split(':').str[0].tolist()
```